# Maven checkstyle violation count

Tags: maven, checkstyle

How can I get Checkstyle to print out the total number of found violations when running the maven task?  For example right now I just total up the number of violations found after each run.

For clarification, I simply want this at the end of my maven task:

```
Checkstyle found XXX violations
```

Checkstyle configuration:

```
<build>
 <plugins>
  <plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.17</version>
   <executions>
    <execution>  
     <id>checkstyle</id>
      <phase>validate</phase>
      <goals>
       <goal>check</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
       <failOnViolation>true</failOnViolation>
       <configLocation>/path</configLocation>
       <maxAllowedViolations>100</maxAllowedViolations>
      </configuration>
     </execution>
    </executions>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>
```

Comment: Could you please include the plugin's configuration you have in your `pom.xml`, your current output and the output you'd like to get?

Comment: @mureinik I cannot include the output. but here is the updated xml

Answer (score 0):

Build the project with “**mvn checkstyle:checkstyle**” command outside the Eclipse. and open the generated checkstyle.html in /Your_Project/target/site folder. You can see the complete report.

Comment: How to count the number of violations ?

Comment: First you need to generate the report!!

Comment: That's not what this question is asking right. Need to have a line after completion of the maven task like `Checkstyle found XXX violations`. So how can you generate that XXX (or the number of violations).

Comment: This is an alternative way, so can chain this task with other tasks to generate the report. eg: mvn clean install checkstyle:checkstyle

Comment: You are giving a way to generate the report. It's not what is asked in the question. or by doing what you've suggested, will there be an output like that with the count ?

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternative way of doing this same thing that would return you the actual number. To do this all you have to do is change the number of allowed violations to 0 and run `mvn clean install` this should run your checkstyle plugin and eventually fail. It will then display the number of violations compared to the number of allowed violations.